# Error with adding foreign key constraints?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a FOREIGN KEY on the MAJORS table that references major in the MAJOR_DESCRIP table. In other words, I want to have a constraint that prevents someone from entering a major that doesn’t have a record in the MAJOR _DESCRIP table.  I am new to primary and foreign keys so I'm not sure what exactly is wrong here. I will provide table data for both below along with what command I'm trying to run and the error message it throws back.  Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I am trying to use to accomplish this:

```
ALTER TABLE MAJORS 
ADD CONSTRAINT MAJORS_FK FOREIGN KEY (Major) references MAJOR_DESCRIP(Major);
```

The error Oracle Apex spits back is - [image]

Comment: Do your tables already contain some data?

Comment: Yes, do you need it?

Comment: Yes please share

Comment: Okay I've added the table data for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Oracle 12c Database SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) contains the following statement:

> A foreign key constraint requires values in one table to match values in another table.

Therefore, to fix the error you must do one of the following actions *before* adding the constraint.

**Solution 1: Add data to `MAJOR_DESCRIP`**

Add 3 rows into the `MAJOR_DESCRIP` table for `Economics`, `Geology` and `Criminal Justice`:

```
INSERT INTO MAJOR_DESCRIP (MAJOR, DESCRIPTION, YRTTRM) VALUES ('Economics', 'Get rich quick', '201801');
INSERT INTO MAJOR_DESCRIP (MAJOR, DESCRIPTION, YRTTRM) VALUES ('Geology', 'Rocks are fun', '201801');
INSERT INTO MAJOR_DESCRIP (MAJOR, DESCRIPTION, YRTTRM) VALUES ('Criminal Justice', 'Crooks and lawyers', '201801');

COMMIT;
```

**Solution 2: Remove data from `MAJOR`**

Delete the rows from `MAJOR` which reference which reference `Economics`, `Geology` and `Criminal Justice`, which are used by `STUDENT_ID`s `900374912` and `900374913`:

```
DELETE FROM MAJOR
WHERE MAJOR IN ('Economics', 'Geology', 'Criminal Justice');

COMMIT;
```

Then you will be able to add the `MAJOR_FK` constraint.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here could be that there would be some values available in **MAJOR** field of **MAJORS** table which would have been unavailable in **MAJOR** field of **MAJOR_DESCRIP** table.

Thus, when you try putting the constraint, your constraint is not getting satisfying because of which you are facing this error.

The best possible solution will be to wipe out data from your **MAJORS** table and then add the constraint, thereafter adding the correct data.

Comment: Or just use a query to find any conflicting data.

Comment: @codeLover I've added the table data like you've suggested but the point of this exercise to add the constraint after the data is put into the table so I'm afraid that's not what I'm looking for here

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Major Column value`  from `Majors Table` then add `foreign key constraint`

Comment: Unfortunately the point of the exercise is to add the constraint after the data has been entered so this will not suffice